# MDX Studio is not responding while trying to debug

Tags: ssas, mdx

Have a problem with MDX Studio 0.4.14.0 while trying to use debug feature.

Connecting to SSAS 2008 R2 (ver.10.50.2500)

[image]

Writing simple mdx query like select sales amount by years from AW

[image]

Next press Debug button. New pane Debug watch appear. While I'm not touching Results pane, everything is OK, but as soon as I click inside the Results, program stops responding. This feature is so great in understanding mdx, how can I repair it? I've tried different servers, different win and sql versions, but error the same. It is very sad =(

[image]